# Color the rows of datatable based on the condition in JSF1.0?

Tags: jsf

How to color the rows of HTMLdatatable based on the condition in JSF 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a commaseparated string of CSS class names to the `rowClasses` attribute of the component. Those CSS class names will be applied on the rows repeatedly. And then of course define the color in those CSS class(es).

Comment: but i want to color the row through managebean according to some condition for example it the value of one filed is "I" the color should be gray,value is "M" then color should be white else if the value is "A" then color should be pink. 
so according to you the color is which I define in rowclasses is fixed for whole table.

Comment: You can just use EL. E.g. `rowClasses="#{bean.rowClasses}"`.

Comment: @BalusC Are you able to change an individual row from an action event in the bean? Say I have a text box to enter which row I'd like to change color. So I enter 5 and click a "Go" button. How would you change the color of the 5th row but not any other row?